# Ionic email composer plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova, email, ionic-framework

I'm facing serious problem with sending an email from my ionic app.

I'm using this cordova plugin

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

This is my code :

Controller :

```
.controller('EmailController', function($scope) {
$scope.sendFeedback= function() {

    if(window.plugins && window.plugins.com.jcjee.plugins.emailcomposer) {
        console.log("test");
        window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(function(result) {
            console.log("Response -> " + result);
        }, 
        "Feedback for your App", // Subject
        "",                      // Body
        ["test@example.com"],    // To
        null,                    // CC
        null,                    // BCC
        false,                   // isHTML
        null,                    // Attachments
        null);                   // Attachment Data
    }
    else console.log("error");

}
});
```

config.xml:`

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email" spec="^1.2.6" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git" />
<plugin name="com.jcjee.plugins.emailcomposer" spec="https://github.com/jcjee/email-composer.git" />
```

The view :

`<ion-view title="Page" >
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
  <button ng-click="sendFeedback()" class="button button-positive button-block">send mail</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>`

When I looked to the log ,the application can't even pass through the if(window.plugins && window.plugins.com.jcjee.plugins.emailcomposer) 
so it shows me : console.log("error");

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `jcjee/email-composer` plugin is really working with recent version of Cordova,
but for `katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer` you can verify plugin availability on your phone with

```
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.email) {
        // now you can check if `cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable()`
    }
```

Comment: the good news that the plugin is available now , but I still can't get a functional controler